# Number of ways in which $3$ people can be selected from $n$ people sitting in a row and if no two of them are consecutive

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Question:
If $P_n$ denotes the number of ways in which three people can be selected from $n$ people sitting in a row and if no two of them are consecutive and $P_{n+1}-P_n=15$, then find the value of $n$.

My attempt:
$P_n=\binom{\frac{n}{2}}{3}$ as three can be selected from $\frac{n}{2}$ people and other $\frac{n}{2}$ people cannot be selected.But I've reached a dead end while solving the problem. Please help me.
The answer is $8$.

Comment: There is no question in this.  Are you asking to find the value of $n$ such that $P_{n+1}-P_n = 15$? Or to prove that for all $n$,  $P_{n+1}-P_n = 15$? (which is surely not true)

Comment: Thanks I've edited it...it's to find the value of n

Comment: Is the answer $n = 8$?

Comment: Yes it's 8 please help

Comment: Your try does not work.  It appears you think the three should all be in even or all be in odd positions, but for $n=6$ they could be $1,4,6$

Comment: Can you describe the reason as to why my answer no longer works for you when it did work for you at the time you asked the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select any $3$ people out of the $n$ seating in a row, the people are divided into 4 regions (a rough sketch like the one below might help).

- - - - -| - - - - - - |- - - - - - |- - - - -

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ be the number of people in the $4$ regions. Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n-3$$
Now, here $x_2$ and $x_3$ can't be $0$, otherwise people selected will become consecutive. But $x_1$ and $x_4$ can be $0$. So, do the substitution $$x_2 = x_2^{'} + 1$$ $$x_3 = x_3^{'} + 1$$
Now as the least value of $x_2$ and $x_3$ is $1$, the least value of $x_2^{'}$ and $x_3^{'}$ is $0$. The new equation becomes 
$$x_1 + x_2^{'} + x_3^{'} + x_4 = n-5$$
Now the multinomial theorem is applicable as all the variables are non-negative. Hence, we get the value of $P_n$ as $\binom{n-2}{3}$. Solve the given equation now to get the value of $n$ as $8$.

Answer (score 0):

First step is finding the closed form of $P_n$, which you've done wrong. Firstly you have to consider the number of all triples, which is $\binom{n}{3}$. Then subtract the 'bad' triples, which have at least two consecutive numbers, you can choose them in $(n-2)(n-1)$ ways, bacause for choosing the first of adjacent pair you can choose from the first $n-1$ numbers, then any of the remaining $n-2$ can be used for the third number. Now comes the tricky part. You have to subtract $n-2$ from the number of consecutive pairs, because if you have counted all triples from three adjacent numbers twice. So we finally we get $\binom{n}{3} - ((n-2)(n-1) - (n-2))$. As now you have closed form of $P_n$, substitute in the equation you have, simplify the expression, you'll get an equation for n, which you can easily solve.